# Why is there no background image in IE7?

Tags: html, css, background, background-image, internet-explorer-7

The background image is missing in ie7; only ie7 has an issue.

The site is here http://www.competition4ct.com/.

This is the call I'm using for the background image:

```
html { background : ("source-file.png");}
```

Why isn't the background image appearing?

Comment: I just took a look on my ie7 machine and it seems that it's pulling through ok.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to be missing the `url` in front of your file name. It should be:

```
body {background-image: url(source-file.png);}
```

Notice that I've also used `background-image` here, not `background`. You can use the `background` shortcut, then it would look something like this:

```
body {background: transparent url(source-file.png) left top no-repeat;}
```

It's also more usual to put a background on the `body` tag, although I'm sure the `html` tag will work in most cases as well.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that's causing the problem, but you need to put "url" in front of the parentheses. May not hurt either to make the body have the background. Finally, just the 'background' property might require more input, as you set several things at once (and you're only trying to do the bg image). So:

```
html { background-image : url("source-file.png"); }
```

or

```
body { background-image : ("source-file.png");}
```

For more info see:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_background.asp

Let us know if any of these solutions solve your problem.

Comment: yea, we made it work with using the body property, thank you.